# Confidence interval for normals of normal model

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval

Suppose $X$ is a normally distributed random variable with unknown mean $\theta$ and known variance $\sigma_{X}^{2}$. Suppose that $Y_{1}, \ldots, Y_{n}$ are random variables that, conditioned on $X$, are independent normally distributed random variables with mean $X$ and unknown variance $\sigma_{Y}^{2}$. We are given observations $y_{1}, \ldots, y_{n}$ of $Y_{1}, \ldots, Y_{n}$, and want to compute a confidence interval for $\theta$.

I've been approaching the problem as follows. Let $(X, \epsilon)$ be an $(n + 1)$-dimensional normal random vector with mean $(\theta, 0)$ and variance
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  \sigma_{X}^{2} & 0 \\
  0 & \sigma_{Y}^{2} I
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $\epsilon_{i} = (Y_{i} - X) / \sigma_{Y}$. We can express $Y = (Y_{1}, \ldots, Y_{n})$ as a linear function of $(X, \epsilon)$:
$$
Y = 
\begin{bmatrix}
  \mathbf{1} & I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  X \\
  \epsilon
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is an all-ones vector. Since linear functions of normal random vectors are also normal random vectors, we have that $Y$ is a normal random vector with mean $\mathbf{1} \theta$ and variance
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  \mathbf{1} & I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \sigma_{x}^{2} & 0 \\
  0 & \sigma_{Y}^{2} I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \mathbf{1} & I
\end{bmatrix}^{\mathsf{T}}
= \sigma_{Y}^{2} I + \sigma_{x}^{2} \mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}^{T}.
$$
The two natural statistics to compute from $Y$ are the mean, $\bar{Y}$, and the vector of deviations from the mean, $Y - \mathbf{1} \bar{Y}$. (If we take the squared norm of the vector of deviations from the mean, and divide by $n - 1$, then we get the sample variance, $S_{Y}^{2}$.) We can express these statistics as a linear function of $Y$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  \bar{Y} \\
  Y - \mathbf{1} \bar{Y}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1}^{\mathsf{T}} \\
  I - \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}^{\mathsf{T}}
\end{bmatrix}
Y.
$$
Using again the fact that a linear function of a normal random vector is a normal random vector, we have that this vector of statistics is a normal random vector with mean $(\theta, 0)$ and variance:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1}^{\mathsf{T}} \\
  I - \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}^{\mathsf{T}}
\end{bmatrix}
(\sigma_{Y}^{2} I + \sigma_{x}^{2} \mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}^{T})
\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1}^{\mathsf{T}} \\
  I - \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}^{\mathsf{T}}
\end{bmatrix}^{\mathsf{T}}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \sigma_{X}^{2} + \frac{\sigma_{Y}^{2}}{n} & 0 \\
  0 & \sigma_{Y}^{2} \left( I - \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}^{\mathsf{T}} \right)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
After all this, we get something very similar to the standard model of IID normal observations:
$$
  \frac{\bar{Y} - \theta}{\sigma_{X}^{2} + \frac{\sigma_{Y}^{2}}{n}}
$$
is a standard normal random variable, and
$$
  \frac{\lVert Y - \mathbf{1} \bar{Y} \rVert^{2}}{\sigma_{Y}^{2}}
  = \frac{(n - 1) S_{Y}^{2}}{\sigma_{Y}^{2}}
$$
is a chi-squared random variable with $n - 1$ degrees of freedom. This feels tantalizingly close to a pivotal quantity that I can use to construct confidence intervals, but I can't quite get the details to work out. Does anyone out there know of a way to get at a confidence interval for $\theta$ (it doesn't have to be using the approach above)?

Another approach I've been attempting is maximum likelihood, although I'd prefer not to rely on asymptotic guarantees since my sample size may be small. We showed above that $Y$ is a normal random vector with mean $\mathbf{1} \theta$ and variance $\sigma_{Y}^{2} I + \sigma_{X}^{2} \mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}^{\mathsf{T}}$. Writing down the log-likelihood function and using the formulas for rank-one updates of determinants and inverses, I get to the following formula:
$$
\ell(\theta, \sigma_{Y}^{2})
= -\frac{n}{2} \log(2 \pi)
+ \frac{1}{2} \log(n)
- \frac{n + 1}{2} \log(\sigma_{Y}^{2})
+ \frac{1}{2} \log\left( \sigma_{X}^{2} + \frac{\sigma_{Y}^{2}}{n} \right)
- \frac{(n - 1) S_{Y}^{2}}{2 \sigma_{Y}^{2}}
- \frac{(\theta - \bar{Y})^{2}}{2 \left( \sigma_{X}^{2} + \frac{\sigma_{Y}^{2}}{n} \right)}.
$$
Solving the first-order condition on $\theta$ gives us the maximum-likelihood estimator $\hat{\theta} = \bar{Y}$. Taking the first derivative of the log-likelihood with respect to $\sigma_{Y}^{2}$, substituting $\theta = \bar{Y}$, and setting equal to zero gives
$$
-\frac{n + 1}{2 \sigma_{Y}^{2}}
+ \frac{1}{2 n} \frac{1}{\sigma_{X}^{2} + \frac{\sigma_{Y}^{2}}{n}}
+ \frac{(n - 1) S_{Y}^{2}}{2 \sigma_{Y}^{4}}
= 0.
$$
Rearranging this equation gives us a quadratic equation in $\sigma_{Y}^{2}$:
$$
(\sigma_{Y}^{2})^{2}
+ \left( (n + 1) \sigma_{X}^{2} - \frac{n - 1}{n} S_{Y}^{2} \right) \sigma_{Y}^{2}
- (n - 1) S_{Y}^{2} \sigma_{X}^{2} = 0.
$$
We can compute the solution to this quadratic equation using the quadratic formula, although I haven't been able to get the result into a particularly nice form.